# Manage acts_as_taggable tags with activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, acts-as-taggable-on

Is it possible? I trying:

```
ActiveAdmin.register ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag do

end
```

But i'm getting an error:

```
undefined method `per_page_kaminari' for ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag(id: integer, name: string, info: text):Class`
```

Comment: what exactly you want to display on this page? A list of tags?

Comment: standard active admin resource page with index and filters

Comment: what about other models? do they display without bugs? there is a conflict between kaminari and will_paginate if you use will_paginate in your project.

Comment: hey, Meliborn, did my last edit helped you? if not I'll have to delete my garbage answer ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try it with:

```
ActiveAdmin.register ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.class_eval do
  ....
end
```

in `admin/tags.rb`, also if you have will_paginate in your Gemfile you'll need this

```
#fix for active_admin
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.page_method_name = :per_page_kaminari
end
```

put it in `config/initializers/kaminari.rb` , name of the file doesn't matter. Restart app.

**Edit** - another idea:

**acts_as_tagable** creates a table **tags**,

so you just create a model `tag.rb` in `app/models`

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and in app/admin/tags.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Tag do
end
```

I have used it this way and it works, can't show you the admin table. :)  will post a screenshot soon.

[image]

Comment: I already have kaminari initializer with this code. Class_eval throw me **block not supplied** error.

Comment: I had the same issue with ActsAsTaggableOn, Kaminari, WillPaginate, and RailsAdmin. Creating the `Tag` class and using it in the RailsAdmin `config.included_models` instead of `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag` worked for me.